# Graph Autoencoder with PyTorch-Geometric

Tags: python, pytorch, point-clouds, pytorch-geometric

I'm creating a graph-based autoencoder for point-clouds.
The original point-cloud's shape is `[3, 1024]` - 1024 points, each of which has 3 coordinates

A point-cloud is turned into an undirected graph using the following steps:

- a point is turned into a node.
- a node's feature is 3 coordinates
- for each node-point find 5 nearest node-points to it. they are connected by an edge
- an edge's feature is the distance between the two node-points that it connects.

I use pytorch-geometric to construct my network and Chamfer distance from pytorch3d [[source](https://pytorch3d.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pytorch3d/loss/chamfer.html)] as a loss function.

The architecture of my network is the following:

**The encoder**:
GAT (3->16) -> GAT (16->24) -> GAT (24->36) -> shape([32*1024, 36])

**The decoder**:
GAT (36-> 24) -> GAT (24->16) -> GAT (16->3) -> shape([32*1024, 3])

All these layers accept node features and edge features. Besides that, I use Dropout and ReLU.

After that, I just get the original graphs: [32, 1024, 3] and predicted graphs: [32, 1024, 3] and feed them to chamfer loss from pytorch3d. I get *some sort of* result, but if I visualize them I can see that the network did not learn anything.

**The question is**: since I compare only nodes' features with chamfer distance, does the network even use the adjacency matrix and edges' features? Do I just need to do some fine-tuning or maybe this model doesn't make any sense?

PS: At this point, I do not care about the architecture or whether 5 nearest neighbors is enough.

Comment: I would recommend to check out the [graph autoencoder example](https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/blob/master/examples/autoencoder.py), but this aims to reconstruct the adjacency matrix. Another point could be to exchange the GAT with models specifically designed for point clouds, see [here](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/cheatsheet.html#point-cloud-neural-network-operators).

Comment: thank you! yes, I saw the first example you shared, and it's not what I need for the same reason you described. the second link is extremely helpful, thanks again!

I'll answer my own question when I have a solution

Comment: do you have any updates on this?